# Dart Flutter bears writing

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I placed a post like this. When the text did not fit, it did not pass when it should have been on the bottom line.

**Code:**

```
body: Container(
        
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Container(
          height: 150,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black 
          ),

        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Container(
          height: 180,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
          ),

          child: Row(
            
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text("Soru sor, kazan", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),),
                    Text("SorSor! uygulaması ile soru sor, para kazan! Tek amacın yaşadığın sorunları soru olarak açmak ve diğer kullanıcıların sorularını yanıtlamak.", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
      )
```

I want it to go to the bottom line when there is no space left. How can I do it?

Comment: Wrap the Text or the Column with FittedBox and choose BoxFit.scaledown .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `Row` widget that you have above the `Padding` and the issue will gone.

```dart
               Container(
                  height: 180,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Soru sor, kazan",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "SorSor! uygulaması ile soru sor, para kazan! Tek amacın yaşadığın sorunları soru olarak açmak ve diğer kullanıcıların sorularını yanıtlamak.",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

[image]